# Why is `fromInteger` allowed to return a polymorphic value but that does not work for other function with return-type-polymorphism

Tags: haskell

1 ) Why is `fromInteger` allowed to return a **polymorphic value** but that does not work for other function of the same style (i.e. return-type-polymorphism) such as `Read` ?

```hs
λ> :t fromInteger 
fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a
λ> :t read
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

In GHCI we can have:

```hs
λ> fromInteger(42::Integer)
42

λ> :t it
it :: Num a => a

λ> :t fromInteger(42::Integer)
fromInteger(42::Integer) :: Num a => a

λ> :t 42
42 :: Num p => p
```

However if we do:

```hs
λ> read "2"
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse

λ> :t read "2"
read "2" :: Read a => a

λ> z = read "2"

λ> z
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse

λ> :t z
z :: Read a => a
```

Moreover at compilation time we get the following error for read rather than the exception:

```hs
trial0 = read ("2"::String)
trial2 = fromInteger(2::Integer)
```

```bash
• Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘read’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Read a0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        trial0 :: a0
          (bound at /Users/maatari/Dev/IdeaProjects/haskell-from-first-principles/basic-datatypes/src/LearningBasicDataTypes.hs:174:1)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance (Read a, Read b) => Read (Either a b)
          -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
        instance Read Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
        instance Read Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
        ...plus 23 others
        ...plus 35 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: read ("2" :: String)
      In an equation for ‘trial0’: trial0 = read ("2" :: String)
    |
174 | trial0 = read ("2"::String)
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

This leads to a second question:

2 ) **What does explains the difference of behavior at compilation and in GHCI?** It seems in GHCI a type class instance is picked and the function fails. But at compilation the ambiguity is not accepted and does not go through, so we can't return a polymorphic value. However, fromInteger can still return a polymorphic value, whether in ghci or at compilation check.

### Edit 1

I was able to reproduce and explain what is happening with read as follows:

```hs
data Mood = Blah | Woot deriving (Show)

class Pretty a where
  pretty :: String -> a
  
instance Pretty Integer where
  pretty x =  read x
  
instance Pretty Double where
  pretty x =  read x 
  
instance Pretty Mood where
  pretty x =  Blah
```

**Now the behavior in GHCI**

```bash
λ> pretty "2"
2
λ> pretty "2.0"
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
λ> pretty "x"
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
λ>
```

My interpretation here is that `Pretty Integer` is picked by default, and therefore succeed for the first one but fail for the last two.

If however I were to type things we would get the right picked if typeclass instance and things would work.

```
λ> pretty "2.0" :: Double
2.0
λ> pretty "x" :: Double
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
λ> pretty "x" :: Mood
Blah
λ>
```

**Now the behavior at compilation**

```hs
trial = pretty "2"
```

```bash
• Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘pretty’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Pretty a0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        trial :: a0
          (bound at /Users/maatari/Dev/IdeaProjects/haskell-from-first-principles/basic-datatypes/src/LearningBasicDataTypes.hs:178:1)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Pretty Integer
          -- Defined at /Users/maatari/Dev/IdeaProjects/haskell-from-first-principles/basic-datatypes/src/LearningBasicDataTypes.hs:163:10
        instance Pretty Mood
          -- Defined at /Users/maatari/Dev/IdeaProjects/haskell-from-first-principles/basic-datatypes/src/LearningBasicDataTypes.hs:169:10
        instance Pretty Double
          -- Defined at /Users/maatari/Dev/IdeaProjects/haskell-from-first-principles/basic-datatypes/src/LearningBasicDataTypes.hs:166:10
    • In the expression: pretty "2"
      In an equation for ‘trial’: trial = pretty "2"
    |
178 | trial = pretty "2" 
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: does trial2 compile if you comment out trial0?

Comment: yes, perfectly. There must be some specific rules with the numeric type classes but i can't find it. Also GHCI must do some specific stuff as well but can't find it. I try to read about `Type defaulting in GHCi` but could still not explain the difference of behavior

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haskell has some ad-hoc type defaulting rules that it uses to resolve ambiguous types for the standard numeric typeclasses. In your examples, `Num a => a` is defaulting to `Integer` so that you don't get an error.

The type defaulting rules are:

```
default Num Integer
default Real Integer
default Enum Integer
default Integral Integer
default Fractional Double
default RealFrac Double
default Floating Double
default RealFloat Double
```

`Read` isn't included in these type defaulting rules, so you'll get an ambiguous type error. However, [GHCi has extended rules for type defaulting](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/6.6/docs/html/users_guide/ch03s04.html#extended-default-rules) where the `Read a => a` value will default to the unit type `()`. This then results in the runtime parse exception that you're observing in GHCi.

By default, you can't observe the type defaulting rules with the `:t` pragma in GHCi because the monomorphism restriction is turned off by default in GHCi since version 7.8.1, so it always gives the most generic type. If you turn on the monomorphism restriction, you'll be able to observe the default type being set.

```
Prelude> :set -XMonomorphismRestriction
Prelude> x = 42
Prelude> :t x
x :: Integer
```

Comment: I'm aware of the ad-hoc type defaulting rules, however i don't see how it applies here, wether at compilation or in the GHCI. Can you outline if possible what is happening. In my understanding type defaulting give you concrete type, not polymorphic type. But  nonthless the result of fromInteger is polymorphic, so where did the default happen ?

Comment: Also I don't think in ghci, the exception is due to a lack of default, to me that's exactly the error i get at compilation. No  default so it is ambigous. However in the GHCI you get an exception because the default picked is wrong, and the function fails.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the later with another example which i will add to my question for illustration

Comment: He actually *is* observing ghci's extended defaulting. That's why he gets an exception instead of an ambiguous type error when running `read "2"`. (It's defaulting to `()`.)

Comment: The `:t` pragma in GHCi won't use type defaulting.

Comment: I think i am following you guys. I have updated  my question with an edit to illustrate my point. So about the read part we seem to be in agreement,  the extended type defaulting is happening in ghci, i just need to understand the rule better i guess.

Comment: However when it comes to numeric literal type class behavior, i don't get it. If a default is applied, it does not matter what `:t` does, it should be applied and the result should be a concrete type that :t should report.  Are we circulating somehow ? As is what is returned is actually a concrete type, but then when :t is called, the value  is parsed again and we are back to square one. Confusing ......

Comment: I found that the monomorphism restriction was causing that behavior with `:t`. See the update.

Comment: @MaatDeamon To see some concrete evidence that this *is* being caused by GHCi's extended defaulting, try evaluating this expression in GHCi: `read "()"`

Comment: I'm somewhat convinced now.  I have been playing with turning them off and also playing with NoMonomorphismRestriction. Will update  or answer my question when i get a  good grip on  it, so you guys  can double check if i understood it well.